# Does a succession of adding/subtracting operations on $n$ terms giving a single number can be explained by a unique operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: A list of $N$ numbers $L:{a_1,a_2,...a_N}$, we start rewriting the list in the following manner. In each step, the list size decreases by $1$, and we need to find the final value. The operation is adding, then subtracting consecutive nos with the sign changing alternately:
Step 1: $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
Step 2: $\{1+2,2-3,3+4,4-5\}$ i.e
              $\{3,-1,7,-1\}$
Step 3: $\{3+(-1),-1-7,7+(-1)\}$
              $\{2,-8,6\}$
Step 4: $\{2-(-8),-8+6\}$  i.e
              $\{10,-2\}$
**Note that we began with subtraction in step 4 as step 3 ended with an addition.**
Step 5: $\{10-(-2)\}$
              $\{12\}$
So the answer is $12$.

The final answer can be found by looking for the pattern in the coefficient, say $c_i$ for every position $i$. Then answer will be $\sum_ic_i.a_i$.
How shall I solve this with some good analysis?

Comment: I hav taken the liberty to propose a new title (the previous one was "find the following value" which was not very informative). Do you agree ?

Comment: @maverick: Why are you subtracting for the first calculation in steps 4 and 5?

Comment: yeah i agree with @quasi shouldn't u be adding?

Comment: @quasi means that logically, it should be $2+(-8)=-6$

Comment: We have [a] => [a]

We have [a,b] => [a+b]

We have [a,b,c] => [a+b, b-c] => (a+2b-c)

We have [a,b,c,d]=> [a+b,b-c,c+d] => (a+2b-c, b-2c+d) => (a+3b-3c+d)

We have [a,b,c,d,e]=> [a+b,b-c,c+d,d-e] => (a+2b-c, b-2c+d, c+2d-e)=>(a+3b-3c+d,b-3c-d+e) => [a+4b-6c+e]

:/ its like half binomial coefficients half weird

Comment: @quasi We need to constantly alternate between the + and - . The first sign in step 2,3,... depend on the last sign of previous step.

Comment: @SakethMalyala It's basically dependent on modulo 4 i.e remainder with 4.

Comment: @maverick: The rules are whatever they are, but somehow, I doubt that you have interpreted them correctly. I think each line starts by _adding_, and then the alternation happens. Can you check the statement of the problem?

Comment: Ok, never mind -- there is a good pattern either way. But still check to make sure.

Comment: Hint: Use unknowns $a_1,...,a_n$ instead of numbers. Work out the answer for $1 \le n \le 6$. There is a clear pattern for the coefficients $c_1,...,c_n$ based on binomial coefficients (with a sign that you have to worry about). But first get some data, then worry. Presumably, the proof will be by induction.

Comment: $1 \le n \le 6$ may not be enough to see the pattern. But $1 \le n \le 9$ should do it. If you have programming ability, write a short program, just keeping track of the coefficients $c_1,...,c_n$ for each term.